# How do I import espresso withID on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I am trying to write a unit test with espresso for my application, but whenever I try to use withId, it cannot be found. How do I fix this?

onView works fine, but when I try onView(withId) it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.webowner.authenticate;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.;


import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testLoginButton_shouldBeDisplayed()
    {
        //
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your complete code and any logs or crash if exist.

Answer (score 3):

You should import following:

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 2):

For AndroidX, checkout out the package `ViewMatchers`:

`import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId`

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers